VNC starts well if it is initiated as root, but it does not work if it is initiated as standard user
It is about corporate PC with Ubuntu 20 on it.
I am trying to make a setup of Tiger VNC Server.
my xstartup file looks like this:
#!/bin/sh

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
export DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=ubuntu

It works when I start VNC Server as root or with sudo, but it does not work when I start it as standard user.
To start the server I use:
vncserver -localhost no

When I start it with sudo, all works ok and I get next output:
New 'hostname:1 (root)' desktop at :1 on machine hostname

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /root/.vnc/hostname:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd hostname:1 to connect to the VNC server.

When I start it as standard user I get some errors and VNC shows black screen. The output looks like this:
New 'hostname:1 (username)' desktop at :1 on machine hostname

Starting applications specified in /home/username/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/username/.vnc/hostname:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /home/username/.vnc/passwd hostname:1 to connect to the VNC server.


vncserver: Failed command '/home/username/.vnc/xstartup': 256!

=================== tail -15 /home/username/.vnc/hostname:1.log ===================

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.10.0 - built Jan 23 2024 20:31:07
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12013000, The X.Org Foundation


Fri Aug 23 09:41:59 2024
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

============================================================================================

Starting applications specified in /home/username/.vnc/xstartup has failed.
Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
        tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm

It seems like there are some permissions issue, but I cannot figure out where.
Thank you!
Will be grateful for your help!
Dima
P.S. What I've tried:

Running just with xterm in xstartup file --> works!

Running with startxfce4 --> works, but with OpenGL errors when I start the application (Ansys). The output in terminal is: "Initialization of glew failed!"

Running with mate-session --> same as point 2.


So Ansys works well over VNC just in one case:

When I am using xstartup file described in the beginning of this message and I am physically logged into that PC with Ubuntu 20. When I reboot computer and I am not doing the physical login, but only through the SSH, then starting of VNC server is not successful (black desktop). In this case it will work only with sudo.

And last point, I don't know how important it is. In order to successfully run the application I needed one of the latest OpenGL, so I used this command to install it:
add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa


What exactly is "Ubuntu 20"? what is the gnome-session version? Purely out of curiosity, are the results any different if you use --builtin in place of --systemd ?

Hi @steeldriver,
Regarding the Ubuntu 20 exact version:
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
Regarding the gnome-session version:
gnome-session/focal,focal,now 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 all [installed]
Regarding your proposal, I've tried just now and it gives black screen.

Hi @steeldriver, one more update: Today I am in the office and I just did login to the Ubuntu PC physically and then I've start the VNC server, and it works. I did physically logout and VNC Server still works. So I don't understand how physical login changes some permissions or rights, or something else is influenced.
